# limits of 2 variable functions which is discontinous

Tags: multivariable-calculus

let f:R^2 to R be defined by f(x,y)={1,if x  irrational

```
                                {-1 if x is rational
```

show that for any point (a,b),limit f(x,y) as x,y tends to (a,b) does not exist.

Comment: What criteria do you know for such a test? What are you allowed to use for this homework question?

Comment: we actually have to find delta depending upon epsilon to prove limit does exist,but i am bit confuse in this question because it's not 1 graph function.do help if u know

Comment: Does $y$ have any influence on the (dis-)continuity? Or is $x$ the only influence?